# Probability density function of difference of two independent random variables in the Laplace domain

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform, convolution, moment-generating-functions

I find clear that the probability density function of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution between the probability density functions of the addends and, for this reason, in the Laplace domain, the convolution "becomes" a product. If I had a difference rather than a sum, what can we say about the relative formulation in the Laplace domain?

Comment: Let $Y := - X$.

Comment: I did but I did't get anything that can be formulated in the Laplace domain

Comment: $\mathcal L \left\{ f (-t) \right\} = F (-s)$

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+antitransform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%28%281+%2B+s%29%281-s%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22s%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22) I applied your equality to get de PDF of the difference of two exponential random variables both with rate 1, but what I get is not a PDF..

Comment: Does [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+antitransform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%281-s%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22s%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22) look like a reflection to you?

Comment: Can you tell me the answer directly or not? No problem in any case, just want to know

Comment: What is so hard about convolving an exponential distribution with its own reflection? Why go to the Laplace domain and fall into traps such as regions of convergence? Why complicate?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(t) := \begin{cases} e^{-t} & \text{if } t \geq 0\\ 0 & \text{if } t < 0\end{cases}$$

Convolving $f$ with its own reflection,

$$\begin{aligned} f (t) * f (-t) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f (\tau) f(\tau - t) \, {\rm d} \tau\\ &= e^t \int_{\max(0,t)}^{\infty} e^{-2\tau} \, {\rm d} \tau\\ &= \begin{cases} \frac 12 e^{-t} & \text{if } t \geq 0\\ \frac 12 e^{t} & \text{if } t < 0\end{cases}\\ &= \frac 12 e^{-|t|}\end{aligned}$$

which is positive and whose integral over the real line is $1$. It is a [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

---

#### In the Laplace domain

Let

$$F (s) := \mathcal{L} \left\{ f (t) \right\} = \frac{1}{s+1}, \qquad \Re\{s\} > - 1$$

and note that

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ f (-t) \right\} = - \left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right) = \frac{1}{1-s} = F(-s), \qquad \Re\{s\} <  1$$

Hence,

$$\mathcal{L} \left\{ f (t) * f (-t) \right\} = F (s) F (-s) = -\frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right) + \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{s+1}\right), \qquad -1 < \Re\{s\} <  1$$

Comment: Ok and that is what I would do but my question is more general. I want to know if a general expression to compute the difference between two random variables not necessarily identical (but independent) exists, like in the case of the sum. All this to avoid integration, like in your answer

Comment: @Luigi2405 Edited the answer.

Comment: Now it's clear but I was looking for a general formulation, if it exists, like the case of the sum of two independent RVs. However, I thank you. Extra question: what's your confidence level with Queueing Theory, I have another question to ask

Comment: @Luigi2405 Isn't it easy to generalize? If you have $Z = X - Y$, then $F_Z (s) = F_X (s) F_Y (-s)$, right? One must be careful with the region of convergence.

Comment: @Luigi2405 If you have another question, then ask it and post the link to it here.

Comment: Yes, of course, but at the link that I posted I do that and do not get your same result, but I think I must take care of existence condition as well, right? I will post it in about two hours

Comment: @Luigi2405 You don't do that *at all* because you don't specify the region of convergence and Wolfram Alpha assumes it.

Comment: Now it's ok, and that region is always the one you wrote in your answer, right?

Comment: @Luigi2405 Always? Just be careful and consider each case separately. If I am not mistaken, Wolfram Alpha thought you had $-e^t$ for $t \geq 0$, when you had $e^t$ for $t \leq 0$.

Comment: I have another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524822/if-x-y-and-z-are-non-identical-and-independent-exponential-random-variables-wh), if you want to help me